# Search for words in user profile content in SEDE

Tags: support, data-explorer

I'd like to find users who have a certain word in their bio, but I have no idea how to do this.

For example, find all users who have "senior" in their bio.

Is there a way to do this with SEDE?

Comment: I don't know whether it's doable but it doesn't feel like something SEDE should offer. Too much potential for misuse. Try Google's advanced search. It seems possible in theory but I wonder why this is not working (it's showing only 2 results): `allintext: senior site:https://www.stackoverflow.com/users/`

Comment: I understand the possible problems such a feature could cause (targeting users). I'm just curious about something and would like to get some recent stats. No problem if it's not possible, I'll try another approach.

Comment: Ahh, got the domain wrong! THis seems to work fine `allintext: senior site:https://stackoverflow.com/users/` (but may no be good enough to get stats.)

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/831501?search=senior also relevant: http://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial

Comment: @rene Perfect. Please make this an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shouldn't be too hard to get at if you follow the [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial/) and study the [Database schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) a bit.

With a minimum of SQL fu, [here it is](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/831501?search=senior):

```sql
select id as [User Link]
from users
where aboutme like '%' + ##search:string?senior## + '%'
```

Keep in mind that SEDE is updated only once a week, on Sunday.